# RPM build errors: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MJ4rSp (%prep)

Tags: linux, fedora, rpmbuild

I'm trying to use the command "fedpkg prep" but when I do I get the following error
RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.MJ4rSp (%prep)
How do I resolve this problem? I'm a newbie to Linux.

Comment: One needs more information to resolve the problem. Please, post the whole log, what package you are building, what Fedora version are you using and so on ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

When I scrolled up to see if I could find an error, I discovered there wasn't enough space in the /boot directory for fedpkg prep to execute